# como condicionar al usuario que solo puede seleccionar 3 checkbox con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Buenas tardes tengo estos input checkbox y no encuentro la manera de condicionr al usuario de que solo puede seleccionar como máximo 3, lo he intentado con javascript pero no me funciona alguien me podría ayudar? este es mi código html.

```
<label class="col-sm-6 control-label no-padding-right" for="TemasDeInteres">Cuáles de los siguientes temas son de tu interés en temas de voluntariado(Maximo 3)</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="Enseñanza">Enseñanza
                        <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="Ciencias y tecnología">Ciencias y tecnología
                        <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="Social">Social
                        <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="socio Sanitario">socio Sanitario
                        <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="Ambiental">Ambiental
                        <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="comunitario">comunitario
                        <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="Culturales y artisticos">Culturales y artisticos
                        <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="Personas con capacidades diferentes">Personas con capacidades diferentes
                        <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="Construcción">Construcción
                        <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="Otro">Otro:
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes ejecutar desde aqui si deseas y veras que funciona como lo quieres

```js
$(".mandatory").on('change',function()
{
    if(seleccionados = $('input:checkbox:checked').length >3)
    {
      alert('No se pueden seleccionar mas de 3 opciones');
      $(this).prop('checked',false);
      return;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="col-sm-6 control-label no-padding-right" for="TemasDeInteres">Cuáles de los siguientes temas son de tu interés en temas de voluntariado(Maximo 3)</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="Enseñanza">Enseñanza
                        <br><input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="Ciencias y tecnología">Ciencias y tecnología
                        <br><input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="Social">Social
                        <br><input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="socio Sanitario">socio Sanitario
                        <br><input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="Ambiental">Ambiental
                        <br><input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="comunitario">comunitario
                        <br><input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="Culturales y artisticos">Culturales y artisticos
                        <br><input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="Personas con capacidades diferentes">Personas con capacidades diferentes
                        <br><input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="Construcción">Construcción
                        <br><input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteres[]" id="TemasDeInteres" class="form-control mandatory" value="Otro">Otro:
                </div>
```

Comment: si me funciono muchas gracias.

Comment: D nada amigo :)

Answer (score 1):

el id de cada item no se recomienda repetir
esta opción creo que te puede funcionar, se ejecutá cada ves que se seleccione una opción, puedes tambien crear una función y antes de guardar verificar si no hay mas de 3 opciones seleccionadas.

```
  $(".mandatory).on('change',function()
    {
    if(seleccionados = $('input:checkbox:checked').length >3)
    {
    alert('No se pueden seleccionar mas de 3 opciones');
    }
    });
```

Comment: hola lo puse así como lo copiaste pero aun así no me funciona.